# Modules on pyCharm don't run, only main does

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with my pyCharm community. When I create a project pyCharm by default creates a module named main. The problem is, when I open another module and try to click on run icon, this module won't run! only the main runs even if it's not opened.
I tried to check run configuration but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click on edit configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF22u.png)

[On the Left panel, click on python, then click on add configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWWep.png)

FInally browse the file you would like to run and apply
Go back to your Run button and run.
Remember to always select the file u want to run from the dropdown before running.